# Search Table For Whole Word In Another Table, If Found Exclude From Result

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Using MS Access, how would I create a query using SQL to search a table containing search terms (1 to 10 word phrases) for keywords or keyword phrases in another table, then exclude any matches to produce a list of search terms that did not match?

### Search Terms Table Sample Data

- tree house design
- nelson tree house master
- attachment point
- attach blinder
- stainless steel nails

### Negative Keywords & Keyword Phrases Sample Data

- sign
- attach
- use
- steel

### Desired Query Output

- tree house design
- nelson tree house master
- attachment point

NOTE: The Negative keywords include 'sign' and 'attach' but this should not prevent 'tree house design' and 'attachment point' from showing up in the result set. I am using Access 2007.

Comment: Im not sure what are you asking. Is `search terms` a table or the thing you want to search? How is related `negative keywords` with search terms and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the query

```
SELECT SearchTerms.Phrase
FROM SearchTerms, Negatives
GROUP BY SearchTerms.Phrase
HAVING (((Max(InStr(" " & [phrase] & " "," " & [exclude] & " ")))=0));
```

Where SearchTerms is a table of the search terms and Phrase is the search term field, Negatives is the table with negative terms to exclude and Exclude is the field name in that table.

The trick is that I added spaces before & after the phrase, then looked for matches with the words to exclude and leading/trailing blanks.  This way I can identify only the phrases that match whole words and not parts of words.

Worked fine when I set up the tables & tested it.

Comment: are you sure you need the leading spaces? " attach " won't match "attach binder"

Comment: yes - you need the leading blanks on both terms so that " attach " will match " attach binder ".  They're needed to pick up matches at either the beginning or end of the search term.

Comment: ok, not sure how adding leading and trailing spaces to both the `phrase` and `exclude` help, should be the same result w/only trailing space after `exclude`

Comment: the leading space is required on both to avoid a match where the negative word is found at the end of a word in the search term - ie, "design" and "sign" do not match

Comment: Awesome Don George! You even solved the problem of no spaces before and after the phrase by adding them to the query. Nice job! I accepted your answer because it 100% works, but I do have another wrinkle to my problem. [working the requirements out now]